# Why `order by time desc` did not work for data of different devices in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now using Version 0.13 of Apache IoTDB, and when I try to use `order by time desc` to order the time series of different devices in descending order of time, the command does not work. Why is this happened and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If there is data of multiple devices that need to do `order by time desc`, Version 0.13 of Apache IoTDB does not support this execution. You can upgrade IoTDB to Version 1.1 or above to execute `order by time desc` in this scenario.